# Does a.e pointwise convergence preserves this property?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

> Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of positive measurable functions such
> that $f_n \geq M>0$ for all $n.\;$ If in addition $f_n
>  \xrightarrow{L^1} f\;$, then is it true that $f \geq M$?

To be honest, I am not even sure if such a property would hold even for uniform convergence. However, I try to understand something at the moment and this question popped up in my head. Unfortunately I could not find any satisfying answer, hence I thought to drop it here.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: it's true that $f\ge M$ almost everywhere, which is the most you can expect. Proof: recall that there is a _subsequence_ converging to $f$ almost everywhere...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

We assume $f_n \stackrel{\mathcal{L}^1}{\to} f$. Since $f_n \geq M$, we have that
$$\int_{\{f< M\}}|f-M|d\mu\leq\int_{\{f<M\}}|f_n-f|d\mu \to0$$
And by Markov's inequality we obtain
$$\mu(\{|f-M|\geq\varepsilon\}\cap\{f<M\})=0 \ \ \ \forall \varepsilon >0$$
In the limit:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu\bigg(\bigg\{|f-M|\geq \frac{1}{n}\bigg\}\cap\{f<M\}\bigg)=\mu(\{|f-M|\geq0\}\cap\{f<M\})= \\ =\mu(\{f < M\})=0$$